# gksu not working in menu mode but works in cli mode

Tags: authentication, gksu

I'm running 12.04, latest updates.
when I use gksu in the menu to start a application the prompt for password doesn't appear and the application starts with user priviledges.
If I use gksu from commmand line everything works just fine.

I need to create a shortcut:
[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me... be specific please

Comment: Hi,

I just need to run applications in graphical mode, using the "gksu application" in the menu to create a shortcut.
This used to work just fine with 10.04 and with 12.04 in the beggining, but after some time it no longer asks for the password and runs as user and not as sudo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> then write : `gksu-properties` and open it.

The first option should be "sudo"

**Authentication mode: sudo**

and change the second option from "enable" to "force enable".

**Grab mode : force enable**

[image]

Then retry to open an application with `gksu`

You can also try the `gksudo` instead of `gksu`

Maybe `gksudo` works better.

### Also you can try to create a new launcher

Open a terminal and issue the following commands

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel
gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/.local/share/applications/ --create-new
```

At the opened window complete the appropriate sections

[image]

**Name: wireshark-root**

**Command: gksudo wireshark**

**Comment: anything you want**

Find the new launcher and try to open it.

Alternatively you can try to replace the **Command: gksudo wireshark**

with **Command: gksudo wireshark &**

maybe the ampersand `&` helps here.

Comment: Hi,

When I try to do "gksu properties" it asks for the password but nothing appears...

Comment: Hi,

It's gksu-properties, with a dash in the middle.
I'm able to run the command and change the option but the result is the same...

Comment: Yes , I've corrected my answer. Is `gksu-properties`. This is run on my machine (Ubuntu 12.04) fine. I don't know why not running in yours. You can also try to use `promt`. Of course the alternative is `gksudo` instead of `gksu`

Comment: gksudo doesn't work also...
the strange thing is that it works if I run the command from command line "gksu wireshark" or "gksudo wireshark", but from the main menu, creating a shortcut doesn't work.
what do you mean with "prompt"?

Comment: With `prompt` I meant the other option in `gksu-properties` , but I think it not matters. Do you want to tell us what shortcut you want to create and How you attempt to create this shortcut ? What desktop environment you use , Unity ?

Comment: I'm using gnome classic and I just want to add a new menu item with "gksu wireshark" to launch wireshark with access to the interfaces and capture traffic.

Comment: Yes , but how ? How you attempted to create this shortcut ? Did you use the `gnome-desktop-item-edit` command ? Also edit your Original question and add the query about the shortcut ,so the question-description to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
After lots of changes and some reboots all started working and to be honest I don't really know what made it work again...

Comment: I needed to change both modes to that suggested here. The result was immediate and successful. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, because I don't really understand what you want to do, but maybe you have to use `/usr/bin/gksu` in a custom starter instead of `gksu`
Please be more specific about your problem and tell us, what you want to do exactly.

Comment: I need to open applications with su priviledges. Graphical applications.